# Hyphen for after 2nd character

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to write a simple function to mask an input with a date like 12-2018 (MM-YYYY) and used a regex like below, but its return the number with a slash for every 2 digits. But I am looking only slash with after first 2 digits only. I have searched for a lot and got below hint only.

```
("122018").match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join("-")
("122018").match(/\d{3}(?=\d{2,3})|\d+/g).join("-")
```

Comment: Can you share why -vote?

Comment: Show sample input and desired output / what should be matched (not my downvote byt he way, but this may the reason)

Comment: I will add fiddle but desired output is there in the question itself.

Comment: We dont understand what you want. Can you write your inputs and expected results like this : 12/2018 → 12-2018

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should simply specify the exact number of characters in the curly braces.  Refer to the capture groups when replacing.

Use '-?' or '.?' to allow an optional (dash or any) delimiter.  Or take it out if you do not want to allow delimiters.

You might want to allow for optional spaces around your input too...

```js
let inputValues = ['122018', '12-2018', '2018']
let res = rx = /(\d{2})(\d{4})/
//let res = rx = /(\d{2})-?(\d{4})/

inputValues.forEach(inputValue => {
  let m = res.exec(inputValue)
  if (m) {
    console.warn('good input: ' + inputValue)
    //console.log(m[1] + '/' + m[2])
  } else {
    console.warn('bad input: ' + inputValue)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I going to try this way, in the meanwhile I would like to ask my input may like this let inputValue = '122018 '

Answer (score 0):

```js
date = '122018';
arr = date.match(/^(..)(.+)$/);
res = [arr[1],arr[2]].join('-');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay! I would like to use "match" instead of "replace" because of some reason. I have already used like replace(/^(.{2})/,"$1-") but it made me difficult to use backspace in the input field.